# Syntax error that I can't figure out

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

Yes I realize I made a mistake about editing original question out, so here it is again; note that I instantly asked another question because I previously had this area in another project I practiced on that I gave up on with the same issue and I couldn't figure out how to fix it.

```
def overwrite():
    print "Which save file would you like to overwrite?"
    print "Save file 1 contains:" x['name']
    print "Save file 2 contains:" y['name']
    print "Save file 3 contains:" z['name']
    ovw=raw_input()
    if ovw.lower() == 1:
        write_data({'name':name, 'fname':'ply.json'}, 'ply.json')
    elif ovw.lower() == 2:
        write_data({'name':name, 'fname':'ply1.json}, 'ply1.json')
    elif ovw.lower() == 3:
        write_data({'name':name, 'fname':'ply2.json}, 'ply2.json')
    else:
        print "I don't understand that. Let's try again."
        overwrite()
```

"x" is causing a syntax error on line three and I don't know why.

Comment: Where is `x` defined? You must assign meaning to a variable name before trying to dereference it.

Comment: It was defined previously.

Comment: On line 3 you need a comma between the string and `x['name']`.

Comment: @Karatepig, if it's a new issue, please create another question instead of editing, and notify us in the comments.

Comment: @tjklemz I thought there was a wait time between making new posts but I realized that that restriction was removed at 10 rep. Making new question now.

Comment: make sure you have balanced all parenthesis in your code

Comment: The reason for that is that part of the value of Stack Overflow is to provide answers to future users who might run into the same question - if you edit away your original question it removes that possibility. You might want to revert your edit once your new question is created.

Comment: @Karatepig, ok. Please put this back to the original question so that the answers and comments make sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Karatepig: if you instantly make a new question after asking the previous one, that shows you made zero effort to solve it yourself.

Comment: @DSM How exactly does that show no effort? I have been working with this code for a couple hours total now and I had that second issue previously and found no way to solve it, so I stripped that area and began working elsewhere on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, the body of the function `overwrite()` should be indented; but I'm assuming that is a copy-and-paste fault. To fix your specific issue, **you need a comma between the arguments for `print`**. It should be:

```
print "Save file 1 contains:", x['name']  # notice the comma before the x
```

*The same goes for the other print statements.*

Also, you have some missing apostrophes/quotes. Where you have `'fname:'ply1.json'`, it should be `'fname':'ply1.json'` (this occurs in two places).

**Edit:**

If you keep getting "unexpected indent" errors, then it is likely that you are mixing tabs and spaces in the file. (I get this all the time when I switch editors...)

Comment: Yes, it is a copy-paste fault. And yes I noticed the missing quotes afterwards, thank you for calling it out.

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: Yes that fixed thing but now there is another issue; everytime I have a colon following a quote there is a syntax error and everything indented below is marked as an unexpected indent. I'll edit in an example.

Answer (score 0):

The print statement with `x['name']`, `y['name']` and `z['name']` are not concatenated properly to the first part of the string. You should show us the actual errors you're receiving. If x['name'] is a string, the line could be properly written as:

```
print "Save file 1 contains:" + x['name'] # plus sign
```

or

```
print "Save file 1 contains:", x['name'] # comma
```

And the same for the print statements for y and z

```
def overwrite():
    print "Which save file would you like to overwrite?"
    print "Save file 1 contains:" x['name'] # x['name'] part is not concatenated properly to the first part of the string
    print "Save file 2 contains:" y['name']
    print "Save file 3 contains:" z['name']
    ovw=raw_input()
    if ovw.lower() == 1:
        write_data({'name':name, 'fname':'ply.json'}, 'ply.json')
    elif ovw.lower() == 2:
        write_data({'name':name, 'fname':'ply1.json'}, 'ply1.json')
    elif ovw.lower() == 3:
        write_data({'name':name, 'fname':'ply2.json'}, 'ply2.json')
    else:
        print "I don't understand that. Let's try again."
        overwrite()
```